# How can I center the <HTML> page to allow background on sides?

Tags: css, html, background, alignment

what I am talking about is as follows:

```
html {
    background: url(../Images/bgplaid.jpg);
    background-repeat: inherit;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 1024px;      
}
```

That css will set the page size to 1024px so on mostly all screen larger, the outside of that the 1024px is the background image.

What I want to know is how can I center the page so it always stays in the center. Currently it is on the left side. with the back ground only showing on the right. I would like to know how I can center the html.

I tried putting the  in a div and `align='center'` and also tried to contain the div and float center. No dice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `margin: 0px auto;`:

```
html {
    background: url(../Images/bgplaid.jpg);
    background-repeat: inherit;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 1024px;      
}
```

Comment: the 0 auto says to give the vertical margins a dimension of 0px and the auto says to give the same margin on both sides, and give as much as possible...just a tip, you don't need the px after the 0's because it is just adding extra size to the file...

Answer (score 0):

put everything after your body in a div with id wrapper `<html><body><div id="wrapper">YOUR HTML CODE</div></body></html>`

```
#wrapper {
width: 1024px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```